# Saving the body of the swiftui push notification (firebase swiftui)

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a request to display a notification in the swiftui app. I can get the notification body data when the application is open, but when it is closed, I can't get any data at all. Is there any way to get them and put them in UserDefaults?

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { isOn, _ in
            print(isOn)
            guard isOn else { return }
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        if let token = fcmToken {
            print(token)
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        // Обработка данных уведомления
        print("Данные уведомления:", userInfo)
        
        // Получение данных уведомления
        if let type = userInfo[AnyHashable("type")] as? String,
           let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any],
           let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: Any],
           let body = alert["body"] as? String,
           let title = alert["title"] as? String {
            
            print("Тип уведомления:", type)
            print("Текст уведомления (body):", body)
            print("Заголовок уведомления (title):", title)
            
            // Получение текущих данных из UserDefaults
            var notifications = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "notifications") as? [[String: String]] ?? []
            
            // Создание словаря с данными уведомления
            let notificationData: [String: String] = ["type": type, "body": body, "title": title]
            
            // Добавление новых данных к существующим
            notifications.append(notificationData)
            
            // Сохранение обновленных данных в UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(notifications, forKey: "notifications")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() // Опционально, если требуется немедленное сохранение
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have more than a small amount of data to store, have a look at `SwiftData`. UserDefauls is for small bits of data, for example, settings etc...

Comment: A push notification isn't really a method that you should use to get data to your app.  When a notification arrives while your app is not in the foreground, iOS displays that notification to the user and you only get to find out about it if the user taps on it.

Comment: *but when it is closed* - Can you clarify if you're attempting to receive notifications while the app is in the background or if the app is not running at all? Also, per @workingdogsupportUkraine UserDefaults is not an appropriate place to put that kind of data.